# Garry's Bombs mod - Liquid Tiberium Bomb leaves irremovable green crystals everywhere

Tags: garrys-mod

[image: A bunch of tiberium crystals on gm_construct]

So, uh... this just happened.

I set off a Liquid Tiberium Bomb from Garry's Bombs and I have all these tiberium crystals on my map now. I don't know how to get rid of them, they make weird retching sounds, they constantly damage me whenever I spawn and worst of all, **they stay on the map even when I restart**.

Restarting the server does nothing.
Starting a new singleplayer game does nothing.
Not even restarting the game works.

**How do I get rid of them?**

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have some automatic save-loader mod? I don't know why or how they'd stay there even after you restarted the game.

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI I do not. Garry's Bombs is just that buggy; you should see all the console errors the mod outputs.

Answer (score 2):

Luckily, it's possible to remove them by using the `gmod_admin_cleanup` command, which will clean everything up on the map and restore it to a clean slate. This will also get rid of anything else you may have on the map, however, so be warned.